# Nightwatch.JS Vercel integration

Tags: nightwatch.js

I am trying to execute Nightwatch tests as part of a Vercel deployment.
I am able to install the required drivers (Chrone and Gecko) using a custom install command, and am referencing them in my test configuration:

[image: nightwatch.json]

The drivers are installed properly. [image: deployment log]

However, I can’t connect to the process when executing the tests:

[image: errors in deployment]

Comment: Can you use `server_path: require('chromedriver').path,` and try once.

Comment: @AlapanDas Yes, same result ;-(

Comment: Which command are you using for test execution ? What I could see your tests are somehow searching for firefox instead of chrome.

Comment: There are three test settings (chrome, firefox, and nojs). I have created a public repo with a minimal configuration where the problem is reproduced: https://github.com/dschmidtadv/nightwatch

Comment: You have to provide separate `server_path` for chrome, firefox and nojs in your nightwatch.json file. the nojs has the server path similar to chrome.

Comment: @AlapanDas chrome and nojs are both Chrome, nojs has just turned off Javascript.

Comment: Okk. Can you check the firefox server_path once then. Because i think that where the problem is.

Comment: @AlapanDas I don't believe so, the Github link I shared doesn't even have a setup for Firefox.